# Server 2008R2- how to limit the time it takes the server from trying map a drive that is no longer available

Tags: windows-server-2008

when we try logging locally to the server, the server hang for hours because one of the network drive is not available.

Comment: This isn't typical Windows Server behaviour, so this suggests that your problem is related to a configuration change you've made. I suppose the first logical questions I might have are - how is the drive being mapped normally, and how is it used. Are any apps or services dependant on the drive that isn't available? What does the event log say. What have you tried already? Help us help you by giving us more information!